# Docker Pull: unauthorized: authentication required

Tags: docker

I found several posts for that problem, but could not solve it:
docker pull ..  leads to unauthorized: authentication required

my config file looks like (vim ~/.docker/config.json):

```
{
  "auths": {
    "https://index.docker.io/v1/": {}
  },
  "credsStore": "desktop",
  "experimental": "disabled",
  "stackOrchestrator": "swarm"
}
```

Is that correct?

Comment: Is this for a public or private image? Is that image on Hub or another registry? What happens if you delete (or move) the `config.json` and let docker recreate it by running `docker login`?